# Check PHP array key for bidimensional arrays

Tags: php, arrays

Can i use array_key_exists to check for a given key into a bidimensional array ? or there is a better way to check for  `['payment']['id']` key ?

I try : `array_key_exists('payment.id',$data)` and `array_key_exists('product.id',$data)`

But can not see it working as expected.

```
Eg. array_key_exists(payment.id,$data), where i have an array :
array(
[payment] array( [id]=>123 [date]=>2016-01-20 ) 
[product] array( [id]=>456 [qtty]=>3 )
)
```

Comment: you can use isset(data['payment']['id'])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this. Give [**this**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php) a read.

```
if (array_key_exists('id', $data['payment'])) {
    echo "The 'id' element is in the payment array.";
}
if (array_key_exists('id', $data['product'])) {
    echo "The 'id' element is in the product array.";
}
```

Comment: Great work´s just fine, Thank you! i can access any level of an array dimension ?

Comment: You're welcome! Yep, you can access any level of the array as long as you're providing proper parameters to the `array_key_exists` function.

Comment: Yes! i check array_key_exists('id', $data[$key]['product'])) , and work´s fine!